# Override list behaviors permission not working the way it should

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, 2013, permissions

I don't get it why Permission: `Override List Behaviors`  -

> Discard or check in a document which is checked out to another user,
>   and change or override settings which allow users to read/edit only
>   their own items

Is not working the way it should.... I have a list with advanced settings configured to: `Read Access`

> Read items that were created by the user

But the users with a permission level set with `override list behaviors` permission can't see the items created other than the author... Why oh why?

Comment: The documents must at least have one published version for the Override List Behaviors to work I think. Before that the items will only show to the creator in the GUI

Answer (score -1):

It only Works with manage lists permissions on, apparently

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange - Could you add a bit more of an explanation such as a reference or additional details to help improve your answer?